# brassbound: synonym of uncompromising?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to describe someone who is an hardcore devotee to her native religion and traditions. Originally, I used "an uncompromising devotee" but after some research, I stumbled on the adjective "brassbound". Unfortunately, my 2 dictionaries don't give much details on the circumstances where this word can be employed. So, do any of you know if I can say "a brassbound devotee"?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The internet has plenty of dictionaries: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brassbound

Seems like you're on target, though if you don't understand the term it might be presumptuous to think that an audience would also understand an archaic term like this; and that might be a better reason to not use the word than the actual definition of the word.

> 2. a. (1) : tradition-bound and opinionated
>        (2) : making no concessions : INFLEXIBLE
>      b. BRAZEN, PRESUMPTUOUS

It may be inappropriate to use it if you think the context of B (brazen/presumptuous) is not accurate.

> Examples of brassbound in a Sentence
>
> a person of brassbound honesty
>
> the brassbound military leadership had failed to realize that this time the nation was fighting a different kind of war